# Grails Detect if a Plugin is Installed

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Is there a way in Grails to Detect that a plugin is installed. For example I need to know if the "Acegi" plugin is installed. If it is then I can run different Code. If the plugin is not installed (which is a viable option) then I can run different code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the plugin manager for this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder

if (PluginManagerHolder.pluginManager.hasGrailsPlugin('acegi')) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [<plugin:isAvailable>](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/isAvailable.html) and [<plugin:isNotAvailable>](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/isNotAvailable.html) tags.

Example using OP's `acegi` plugin:

```
<plugin:isAvailable name="acegi">
    You have acegi installed!
</plugin:isAvailable>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Update for Grails 2.4+

Note that the specific holder classes such as `PluginManagerHolder` have all been deprecated for several versions of Grails, and removed in Grails 2.4.  They have been replaced by a single [`grails.util.Holders`](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/Holders.html) class providing access to all the various application-wide objects through a single access point.

```
import grails.util.Holders

if (Holders.pluginManager.hasGrailsPlugin('acegi')) {
   ...
}
```