# how to detect is plugin installed on grails 2.4.4

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a problem, with detecting installed plugin. I need to check if the plugin installed. For example I need to know if the "MyPlugin" plugin is installed. I try to use PluginManagerHolder like in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941216/grails-detect-if-a-plugin-is-installed), but it removed in grails 2.4.4. Please help with your solutions.  Thanks for help.

Comment: [I've added an answer to the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28560607/592139) explaining the `Holders` class that replaces the various specific `XyzHolder` classes in more recent Grails versions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails Detect if a Plugin is Installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941216/grails-detect-if-a-plugin-is-installed)

Comment: Thank you [Ian Roberts](http://stackoverflow.com/users/592139/ian-roberts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject [`GrailsPluginManager`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/api/grails/plugins/GrailsPluginManager.html).  Example code from [`PluginTagLib`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.4.x/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/PluginTagLib.groovy):

```
GrailsPluginManager pluginManager

boolean checkPluginExists(name, version) {
    if (name) {
        if (version && pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin(name, version)) {
            return true
        }
        if (pluginManager.hasGrailsPlugin(name)) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: As a bean, not a service.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution too. 
In resorces.groovy:

```
def pluginManager=createApplicationContext().getBean('pluginManager')

if (pluginManager.hasGrailsPlugin("MyPlugin")) { 
   do something ...
    }
```